# Random number changes every time an event happens

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

So I have this array of colors in my data and I'm getting a random element from it by using `Math.random()` the problem is every time I click on `<v-autocomplete :items="types" label="User type" multiple v-model="filters"></v-autocomplete>`
the random color changes.
Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
    :key="index"
    style="width:200px;height:200px;"
    :style="'background-color:' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)]"
    v-for="(item, index) in items"
   >
  </div>
  <v-autocomplete :items="types" label="User type" multiple v-model="filters"></v-autocomplete>
</div>
</template>
```

my data:

```
data: () => ({
 items: [
  {
    name: "a"
  },
  {
    name: "b"
  },
  {
    name: "c"
  }
 ],
 colors: [
  "#C004D9",
  "#AB05F2",
  "#A69C0F",
  "#2745F2",
  "#1B78F2",
  "#F2BE22",
  "#F2E635",
  "#F29849",
  "#2405F2",
  "#6503A6",
  "#010440",
  "#F2E74B"
  ],
  types: ["user", "admin", "manager"]
})
```

My question is can I stop Vue from updating the random number when I click on something or change some data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data properties or computed properties the colorful DIVs references will not change when click 'AutoComplete', you may consider below two solutions:

**Solution 1:**

Uses the directive [v-once](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Cheap-Static-Components-with-v-once):

> Rendering plain HTML elements is very fast in Vue, but sometimes you
> might have a component that contains a lot of static content. In these
> cases, you can ensure that it’s only evaluated once and then cached by
> adding the v-once directive to the root element

```js
Vue.use(VAutocomplete.default)

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {return {
   items: [
    {
      name: "a"
    },
    {
      name: "b"
    },
    {
      name: "c"
    }
   ],
   colors: [
    "#C004D9",
    "#AB05F2",
    "#A69C0F",
    "#2745F2",
    "#1B78F2",
    "#F2BE22",
    "#F2E635",
    "#F29849",
    "#2405F2",
    "#6503A6",
    "#010440",
    "#F2E74B"
    ],
    types: ["user", "admin", "manager"],
    filters: []
  }}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/v-autocomplete@1.8.2/dist/v-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-autocomplete :items="types" label="User type" multiple v-model="filters"></v-autocomplete>
  <div v-once>
    <div
    :key="index"
    style="width:200px;height:200px;"
    :style="'background-color:' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)]"
    v-for="(item, index) in items"
   >
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2**:

Wraps the colorful DIVs into one component, if the dependencies of the component don't trigger the reactivity, the component will not be updated.

```js
Vue.use(VAutocomplete.default)
Vue.component('v-color', {
    'template': `
  <div>
    <div
    :key="index"
    style="width:200px;height:200px;"
    :style="'background-color:' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)]"
    v-for="(item, index) in items"
   >
  </div>
  </div>
  `,
  data () {
    return {
     colors: [
      "#C004D9",
      "#AB05F2",
      "#A69C0F",
      "#2745F2",
      "#1B78F2",
      "#F2BE22",
      "#F2E635",
      "#F29849",
      "#2405F2",
      "#6503A6",
      "#010440",
      "#F2E74B"
      ],
     items: [
      {
        name: "a"
      },
      {
        name: "b"
      },
      {
        name: "c"
      }
     ],
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {return {
    types: ["user", "admin", "manager"],
    filters: []
  }},
  methods: {
    clickSomething() {
        this.types.push('a')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/v-autocomplete@1.8.2/dist/v-autocomplete.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <!-- <v-autocomplete :items="types" label="User type" multiple v-model="filters"></v-autocomplete> -->
  <v-autocomplete :items="types" label="User type" multiple v-model="filters"></v-autocomplete>
  <v-color></v-color>
</div>
```

or as the answer from @Rick, you can pre-calculate the color value for each DIVs first in data properties or computed properties, then binds it to the `:style="color:_"`

Answer (score 1):

you don't want to have a random function in your style. That style is going to fire an indefinite number of times.

instead create a variable when the page loads that gets populated by your random function. Then use that variable to define your style.